# Ryan air boarding pass printout

Tags: tickets, ryanair

I have a Ryan air flight from Copenhagen tomorrow morning. Do I really need to print the boarding pass as in the pdf it is mentioned that visa check is required? Unfortunately, I couldn't take the printout as every thing was closed today.

If yes, is it possible to print the boarding pass at the airport in the morning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the Ryan air counter at the airport and showed them the PDF on my mobile phone along with my passport. The agent at the counter just checked my visa and gave me a printed version of the boarding pass for free.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question and feel free to accept the answer, as it is how you found it to be in real life.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you would have to print your boarding pass in this case, because with "visa check required" you will not get the mobile boarding pass, and the Ryanair mobile app will not show the boarding pass. Thus you won't be able to get through security without it. The PDF they sent you is not a mobile boarding pass.

It is possible to do this at the airport, but check the prices - being Ryaiair, it might be quite pricey [and their CEO might be rude about it](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/news/ryanair/Ryanair-boss-slams-idiot-who-forgot-boarding-pass/).